# v-checkbox not rendering in Vuejs / Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I just want a checkbox on my page, but the checkbox graphic itself wont render.
I thought that the problem might be Vuetify, but other components, such as v-btn worked fine in my project so far.

[The checkbox logic itself works fine and the false changes to true once the invisible checkbox is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2diZm.png)

My vue file:

```
<template>
    <v-layout column>
        <v-container
        class="px-0"
        fluid
        >
            <v-checkbox
            v-model="checkbox"
            :label="`Checkbox 1: ${checkbox.toString()}`"
            ></v-checkbox>
        </v-container>

    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            checkbox: false
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.breakers {
    word-break: normal;
}
</style>
```

My main.js file

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import store from '@/store/store'
import Panel from '@/components/globals/Panel'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.component('panel', Panel)

sync(store, router)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>'
})
```

Comment: Your component and main.js file looks fine, try answers to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636717/v-checkbox-icon-missing-with-vuetify-mdi-js-whats-the-best-way-to-import-it) and make sure that you've imported both fonts required by vuetify in your index.html file - it's described here (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/)

Comment: Thanks alot! That fixed my issue. I did not include the fonts in my index.html.